# Adding a market to a line chart Plotly python

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to add a point to the last observation on a time series chart with plotly. It is not very different from the example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72539011/3021252 for instance. Except it is the last observation. Unfortunately following such pattern modifies the axis range.

Here is an example of an original chart

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("country=='Canada'")
fig = px.line(df, x="year", y="lifeExp", title='Life expectancy in Canada')
fig.show()
```

[image]

But after adding a marker

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=[df["year"].values[-1]],
        y=[df["lifeExp"].values[-1]],
        mode='markers'
    )
)
```

It looks like that
[image]

Has anyone have an idea how not to introduce this gap on the right?

Comment: Are you running the first and second code in jupyter notebook or something? The first one is drawing a line chart in express. Then you assign it to fig and do fig.show(). Next, a scatter plot is drawn with a graph object.

Comment: To have the same x-axis as in the first graph drawn, we need to specify the range of the x-axis.

Comment: try this: `fig = go.Figure();fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df["year"],y=df['lifeExp'],mode='lines',showlegend=False));fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[df["year"].values[-1]],y=[df["lifeExp"].values[-1]],mode='markers',showlegend=False));fig.update_xaxes(range=[1952, 2007]);fig.show()`

Comment: Hey, looks interesting. Do you know whether I can get x-axis range from the original figure?

Comment: For the data in question, it would be the minimum and maximum values for the year. `range=[df['year'].min(),df['year'].max()]`

Comment: I get that thanks